# I want to store the prime numbers from 3 to 100 and store them in an array without using constructor

Tags: java, arrays

I have done the program in java but it is not working as desired.I wanted to find the prime numbers(not using constructors or methods) and store them in an array but the result is different.

```
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String []args){
        int s[]=new int[100];
        for (int i=3;i<=100;i++){
            int c=0;
            for (int j=1;j<=i;j++){
                if (i%j==0){
                c++;
                }
            }
            if (c<3){
                for (int a=0;a<s.length;a++){
                    s[a]=i;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int b=0;b<s.length;b++){
                System.out.println(s[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Expected :
3
5
7
.
.
.
97

Output got :

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Pain is to Painting, or Ham is to Hamster. They are completely different. It is highly recommended that aspiring coders try to learn the name of the language they're attempting to write code in. When you post a question, please tag it appropriately.

Comment: `for (int a=0;a<s.length;a++){ s[a]=i; }` This will override all values in the array with the same value `i`.

Comment: @CertainPerformace well, I consider painting a bit of a pain... :)

Answer (score 4):

The mistake is here:

```
for (int a=0;a<s.length;a++){
    s[a]=i;
}
```

Whenever you have found a prime, you set *every* element of `s` to that number, which means that eventually, `s` will be filled with the last prime you found - 97.

Instead of filling the array with whatever prime number you found, declare a new variable called `next` that keeps track of where should the next prime number go in the array:

```
int s[]=new int[100];
int next = 0; // the first prime should go in index 0
for (int i=3;i<=100;i++){
    int c=0;
    for (int j=1;j<=i;j++){
        if (i%j==0){
            c++;
        }
    }
    if (c<3){
        s[next] = i; // put it in next
        next++; // the next prime should go in the next index
    }
}
for (int b=0;b<next;b++){ // only loop to "next", because the indices past "next" are not set
    System.out.println(s[b]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is Working:**

```
public class Prime {
    public static void main(String []args){ 
        int[] primes = new int[100];
          int ncounter = 0;
          int isPrime = 2;
          while( ncounter < 100){
            boolean prime = true;
            for (int j=2; j<isPrime; j++){
              if (isPrime%j ==0){
                prime = false;
                break;
              }
            }
            if (prime){
              primes[ncounter] = isPrime;
              ncounter++;
            } 
            isPrime++;
           }
          return primes;
        }
    }
```